# How to add documentation to enum associated values in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to add descriptions to associated values of enums in Swift 3? I want them to show up in the symbol documentation popup (option+click), like they do for function parameters in Xcode 8.

This is my enum:

```
enum Result {
    /**
    Request succeeded.

    - Parameters:
      - something: Some description.
      - otherThing: Other description.
    */
    case Success(something: Int, otherThing: Int)

    /**
    Request failed.

    - Parameter error: Error.
    */
    case Error(error: Error)
}
```

I tried using `- Parameters:`, but it doesn't work in enums.

Answer (score 35):

Xcode already supports [`Parameter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Parameter.html) for Enum, just like [Xiao Wang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71727902/1260976).

An example is as follows:

```swift
/// Enum Description
enum Enum {
    /// enum1 Description
    /// - Parameter value1: value1 Description
    /// - Parameter value2: value2 Description
    case enum1(value1: Int, value2: String)

    /// enum2 Description
    case enum2
}
```

The effect is as follows:
[image: Enum Parameter]

---

**Below is the old answer.**

Do it like this:

```
/// Enum Description
enum Enum {
    /// enum1 Description
    /// - value1: value1 Description
    /// - value2: value2 Description
    case enum1(value1: Int, value2: String)

    /// enum2 Description
    case enum2
}
```

---

Show result:
[image]

Comment: I suggest to add `Parameter`, otherwise it may be shown in the quick help's "Discussion" section

Comment: The other answer uses the built-in Parameter formatting, which should be used. The other answer is better for this reason, and this should be removed unless its owner edits it.

Answer (score 18):

It looks like `- Parameter` works fine.

```
enum Vegetable {
    
    /// Potato.
    /// - Parameter variety: Variety of potato.
    /// - Parameter mass: Mass of a potato in kilograms.
    case potato(variety: String, mass: Float)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, good find!